# programmatic date validation returning async? (jquery formvalidator)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-form-validator

I have a form with a text field populated by datepicker() that I am trying to validate programmaticaly in the click event handler for a button:

```
var formValid = true;

console.log( Date.now() + ' initial value: ' + formValid );

$('#expiryDate').validate(function(valid,elem){
    if(!valid){ formValid = false; }
    console.log( Date.now() + ' in expiryDate validate: ' + formValid );
});

console.log( Date.now() + ' after expiryDate validate: ' + formValid );

$('#documentName').validate(function(valid,elem){
    if(!valid){ formValid = false; }
    console.log( Date.now() + ' in documentName validate: ' + formValid );
});

console.log( Date.now() + ' after documentName validate: ' + formValid );

if(!formValid){
    console.log( Date.now() + ' no post...' );
    $('.btn').prop('disabled' ,false );
    return;
} 

console.log( Date.now() + ' would post now...' );

//$.post();
```

The validation for documentName returns correctly and synchronously. However, the validation for expiryDate does not: formValid is still true when it evaluates it to decide whether to return or to do the $.post().

If I add console.log() outputs, I am seeing that the validator for the expiryDate field is returning well after the code would have already executed the $.post().

As a result, the data is submitted via $.post() even though the validation is failed.

What am I missing?

Here are the console.log() results (the numbers are a tick count for checking timing; true/false refers to the value of formValid):

```
1526495506879 initial value: true
1526495506881 after expiryDate validate: true
1526495506882 in documentName validate: true
1526495506883 after documentName validate: true
1526495506883 would post now...
1526495507084 in expiryDate validate: false
1526495507086 in expiryDate validate: false
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you nest one validation inside the callback of the other, then the post request inside the inner validation callback, like so:

```
var formValid = true;

console.log(Date.now() + ' initial value: ' + formValid);

$('#expiryDate').validate(function (valid, elem) {
    if (!valid) { formValid = false; }
    console.log(Date.now() + ' in expiryDate validate: ' + formValid);

    $('#documentName').validate(function (valid, elem) {
        if (!valid) { formValid = false; }
        console.log(Date.now() + ' in documentName validate: ' + formValid);

        if (!formValid) {
            console.log(Date.now() + ' no post...');
            $('.btn').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            console.log(Date.now() + ' would post now...');
            //$.post();
        }
    });
});
```